Problema deployando proyecto rollup y sass en vercel
Tengo un proyecto que compila con rollup mi codigo javascript y para el frontend compila con sass, la situacion es que al intentar deployarlo en vercel, se queda pegado haciendo el archivo de codigo compilado:

Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning github.com/NathalyQuiva/portfolio_javascript (Branch: main, Commit: 99bc1d4)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 483.234ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 34.1.10
Installing dependencies...
added 1 package in 486ms
Detected package-lock.json generated by npm 7+
Running "npm run build"
portafolio@1.0.0 build
rollup --watch --config --sourcemap
rollup v2.79.0
bundles src/index.js → public/bundle.js...
created public/bundle.js in 42ms

Se queda allí.
